# SQL 2008 Exists

Tags: sql, exists

I have 2 tables **`TimetableMaster`** and **`TimetableBreakup`**. In my stored procedure, i need an IF condition to check whether `TimetableMaster`.`TimetableMasterID` exists in the `TimetableBreakup` table(for which `TimetableMasterID` is the foreign key). How do I frame the IF condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
 Select * from TimetableMaster where TimetableMasterID in (select TimetableMasterID  from TimeTableBreakup)
```

or

```
 Select * from TimetableMaster where TimetableMasterID exists (select TimetableMasterID  from TimeTableBreakup)
```